# Python: how to find value in list smaller than target

Tags: python

For example I have a non-ordered list of values [10, 20, 50, 200, 100, 300, 250, 150]

I have this code which returns the next greater value:

```
def GetNextHighTemp(self,  temp,  templist):
    target = int(temp)
    list = []
    for t in templist:
        if t != "":
            list.append(int(t))
    return str(min((abs(target - i), i) for i in list)[1])
```

e.g. If temp = 55, it will return '100'.

But how can I get the lesser of the value? That is how to get it to return '50'?

Thank you.

**EDIT - now working**

```
def OnTWMatCurrentIndexChanged(self):
    self.ClearTWSelectInputs()
    material = self.cb_TW_mat.currentText()
    temp = self.txt_design_temp.text()
    if material != "":
        Eref = self.GetMaterialData(material,  "25",  "elast")
        if Eref and Eref != "":
            Eref = str(float(Eref) / 1000000000)
            self.txt_TW_Eref.setText(Eref)
        else:
            self.txt_TW_Eref.setText("194.8")
            self.ShowMsg("No temperature match found for E<sub>ref</sub> in material data file. Value of 194.8 GPa will be used.",  "blue")
    if material != "" and temp != "":
        if self.CheckTWTemp(material,  temp):
            dens = self.GetMaterialData(material,  temp,  "dens")
            self.txt_TW_dens.setText(dens)
            elast = self.GetMaterialData(material,  temp,  "elast")
            elast = str(float(elast) / 1000000000)
            self.txt_TW_Et.setText(elast)
            stress = self.GetMaterialData(material,  temp,  "stress")
            stress = str(float(stress) / 1000000)
            self.txt_TW_stress_limit.setText(stress)
        else:
            self.ShowMsg("No temperature match found for " + temp + "&#x00B0; C in material data file. Extrapolated data will be used where possible or add new material data.",  "blue")
            dens = self.GetExtrapolatedMaterialData(material,  temp,  "dens")
            self.txt_TW_dens.setText(dens)
            elast = self.GetExtrapolatedMaterialData(material,  temp,  "elast")
            elast = str(float(elast) / 1000000000)
            self.txt_TW_Et.setText(elast)
            stress = self.GetExtrapolatedMaterialData(material,  temp,  "stress")
            stress = str(float(stress) / 1000000)
            self.txt_TW_stress_limit.setText(stress)
    else:
        self.ClearTWSelectInputs()

def CheckTWTemp(self, matvar, tempvar):
    for material in self.materials:
        if material.attrib["name"] == matvar:
            temps = material.getiterator("temp")
            for temp in temps:
                if int(temp.text) == int(tempvar):
                    return True
            return False

def GetMaterialData(self, matvar, tempvar, tag):
    for material in self.materials:
        if material.attrib["name"] == matvar:
            temps = material.getiterator("temp")
            for temp in temps:
                if temp.text == tempvar:
                    value = temp.find(tag)
                    return value.text

def GetExtrapolatedMaterialData(self, matvar, tempvar, tag):
    try:
        templist = QStringList()
        for material in self.materials:
            if material.attrib["name"] == matvar:
                temps = material.getiterator("temp")
                for temp in temps:
                    templist.append(temp.text)
        templist.sort()
        target = int(tempvar)
        x1 = max(int(t) for t in templist if t != '' and int(t) < target)
        x2 = min(int(t) for t in templist if t != '' and int(t) > target)
        y1 = float(self.GetMaterialData(matvar, str(x1), tag))
        y2 = float(self.GetMaterialData(matvar, str(x2), tag))
        x = target
        y = y1 - ((y1 - y2) * (x - x1) / (x2 - x1))
        return str(y)
    except Exception, inst:
        return "0"
```

Comment: To understand why this isn't working, I'd need to see the contents of the `templist` you're passing in.

Comment: Please show how you're calling the function.  Having a first parameter of `self` only makes sense if this is a method in a class, but nothing in here uses `self`.

Comment: Ah I see from your other answer (which you should delete) that all the values in the list get filtered, so max fails. Add that error message to the above; that helps. But also tell us more about `templist`.

Comment: Nice -- my only thought is that if there's another error in that `try, except` block, it will get squashed, and a confusing bug could result. In general, I think it's a good rule of thumb to use small `try, except` blocks and to catch only expected exceptions, like `ValueError` in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: Ah, I used `templist` instead of `list` -- hence the confusion. I didn't mean it to be a one-line function; you still have to do the conversions. (Of course, as Mike DeSimone rightly points out, using list as a variable name is a terrible idea!! So I had a good reason for being confusing. :)

To be more explicit about it, here's a slightly streamlined version of the function (fixed to test properly for an empty list):

```
def GetNextHighTemp(self, temp, templist):
    templist = (int(t) for t in templist if t != '')
    templist = [t for t in templist if t < int(temp)]
    if templist: return max(templist)
    else: return None                   # or raise an error
```

Thanks to Mike for the suggestion to return `None` in case of an empty list -- I like that.

You could shorten this even more like so:

```
def GetNextHighTemp(self, temp, templist):
    try: return str(max(int(t) for t in templist if t != '' and int(t) < int(temp)))
    except ValueError: return None      # or raise a different error
```

Comment: senderle,Thanks a lot, it works! To get the original max value, is there a shorter form as well instead of my 10 lines?

Comment: Oh, I got it, it's just return str(min(t for t in templist if t > target))

Comment: The target IS converted to int, that is not the problem. I think it's something to do with the list-argument I'm passing. When I declare a list variable with string values (to simulate the list) it all works, but it doesn't work with the actual passed list argument.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone, I was thinking of the line as a drop-in replacement for the return line in the OP's post, which already does the necessary conversions.

Comment: @senderle Well, both of them work with the templist defined in the function but not when it's passed from another place. Will have to look into it more. Thank you.

Comment: @senderle: I'd recommend naming your temporary list `int_temp_list` or `intTempList` instead of `list`, which masks a built-in function. Also, you might want a `try` block to catch the empty-list case, though there are several things that could be done in that case (return `None`, raise a clearer exception, or return `temp`).

Comment: I get the 'templist' from an XML. @senderle, what did you mean by "all the values in the list get filtered"? I don't filter them, just get all temperatures from the XML and append them to the templist and then pass that to GetHigherTemp. And yes, GetHigherTemp is a method in a class.

Comment: @Mike, yeah I just noticed that. Dumb of me.

Comment: @user665327, the `for` loop in the original version of your function acted as a filter; it filtered out empty strings. `[int(t) for t in templist if t != '']` is a shorter version of the same thing; it's equivalent to the built-in `filter` function. If the list is empty, then all the values have been filtered out for some reason.

Comment: @senderle of course, I'm slow, couldn't get what filter you're talking about. And BTW now that I realised I do filter empty strings, it's an even bigger mistery why the passed list doesn't work.

Comment: And when I give it a '0', it throws "ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
"

Comment: @user665327, apologies -- yesterday was not a good day for me apparently. The above code works now.

Comment: @senderle, thank you, I've just thought of an exception last night as well as I couldn't figure out any easy way of catching a non-existent lower value in the list. I've edited my original post with my working property.

Answer (score 24):

A better and much faster (code and cpu wise) way is to use bisect module which does binary search but for that you will need to sort the list first, here is the sample usage:

```
import bisect

mylist = [10, 20, 50, 200, 100, 300, 250, 150]
mylist.sort()

index = bisect.bisect(mylist, 55)
print "Greater than target", mylist[index]
print "Smaller than or equal to target", mylist[index-1]
```

output:

```
Greater than target 100
Smaller than or equal to target 50
```

Also you will need to check the returned index, if it is `0` it means you have passed target lower than the lowest

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work at all. The above solution at least finds the greater value, this doesn't find anything.

Comment: Oh, it does work, but again, only with a set list, not passed list. And it only works if it can find a lower value. e.g. if my target is '0', then it returns '300'.

Comment: @user665327, it will work with any list, I have given you a generic way to do binary search, all other solution seem to be reinventing wheel, and this is faster too, modify it for your usage

Comment: See the docs for bisect_left and bisect_right @Anurag is right about it working. https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html

Answer (score 2):

```
nextHighest = lambda seq,x: min([(i-x,i) for i in seq if x<=i] or [(0,None)])[1]
nextLowest  = lambda seq,x: min([(x-i,i) for i in seq if x>=i] or [(0,None)])[1]
```

Here's how this works: Looking at `nextHighest`, the argument to min is a list comprehension, that calculates the differences between each value in the list and the input x, but only for those values >= x. Since you want the actual value, then we need the list elements to include both the difference to the value, and the actual value. Tuples are compared value by value, left-to-right, so the tuple for each value `i` in the sequence becomes `(i-x,i)` - the min tuple will have the actual value in the `[1]`'th element.

If the input x value is outside the range of values in seq (or if seq is just empty), then the list comprehension will give us an empty list, which will raise a ValueError in `min`.  In case this happens, we add the `or [(0,None)]` term inside the argument to `min`.  If the list comprehension is empty, it will evaluate to False, in which case min will instead look at the sequence containing the single tuple `(0,None)`.  In the case, the `[1]`'th element is None, indicating that there were no elements in seq higher than x.

Here are some test cases:

```
>>> t = [10, 20, 50, 200, 100, 300, 250, 150]
>>> print nextHighest(t,55)
100
>>> print nextLowest(t,55)
50
>>> print nextHighest([],55)
None
>>> print nextLowest([],55)
None
>>> print nextHighest(t,550)
None
```

Comment: It says "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'". I've only used Python for a couple of months, but what you wrote there is very scary :)

Comment: There was a typo in my routines, referencing the variable t instead of the parameter seq.  Should work now.

Comment: When I give it '0', it throws "ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence"

Answer (score 2):

Let the unordered list be `myList`:

`answer = max(x for x in myList if x < temp)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the greatest value that is less than your target; e.g. in your example, if your target is 55, you want 50, but if your target is 35, you want 20.  The following function should do that:

```
def get_closest_less(lst, target):
    lst.sort()
    ret_val = None
    previous = lst[0]
    if (previous <= target):
        for ndx in xrange(1, len(lst) - 1):
            if lst[ndx] > target:
                ret_val = previous
                break
            else:
                previous = lst[ndx]
    return str(ret_val)
```

If you need to step through these values, you could use a [generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) to get the values in succession:

```
def next_lesser(l, target):
    for n in l:
        if n < target:
            yield str(n)
```

Both these worked properly from within a simple program.

Comment: No it doesn't work. It worked in Python console when I tested it, but it doesn't work in my program for some reason. It gives me this error: "max() arg is an empty sequence"

Comment: @user665327:  It's not 100% clear to me what you're trying to get here.  Nonetheless, I've added a function to get the greatest value from the list which is less than your target value - which is what I think you want.  It worked from a simple test program.  If this works from a Python console, but not your program, there may be other problems within your program.  Also, be aware that a generator's results need to be consumed within a loop, just trying to get a single value won't work.

Comment: I have a list of temperatures and need to find both the previous lesser value and the next greater value from the list. Sorry, I'm not familiar with the generator yet.

Comment: @user665327:  Now that you've clarified, you don't need the generator; however, to learn more about them, follow the link in the answer.  Anyway, the function I provided - and those in several other answers - give you the previous lesser value, and you said you already have the next greater value, so you should be good.  For efficiency, these could both be searched for in one loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[4,3,8,2,5]
temp=4
def getSmaller(temp,alist):
    alist.sort()
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        if(i>0 and alist[i]==temp):
            print alist[i-1]
        elif(i==0 and alist[i]==temp):
            print alist[i]
getSmaller(temp,a)
```