# Python find last date before X in series

Tags: python, datetime, match

I'm trying to find one date in a date series, if I cant find that one, I'd rather take the most recent one which is earlier than this date, this is the idea of MATCH function in Excel where you can choose to set MATCH_TYPE to be 0 (exact), -1 (less than) and 1 (greater than).

But I didn't find an equivalent and simple way in Python.

Could anyone shed some lights on this?

### Thanks in advance!

I found out my own solution based on the helpers below:

```
def matchLE(to_match,sorted_match_series):
    match_series[~(to_match < match_series)].argmax()
```

Answer (score 1):

This returns the closest date (higher or lower):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def find_closest(mydate, dates):
   return min(dates, key=lambda x:abs(x-mydate))

dates = [dt(2014, 1, 1), dt(2014, 1, 10), dt(2014, 1, 18), dt(2014, 1, 31)]

print find_closest(dt(2014, 1, 7), dates)
print find_closest(dt(2014, 1, 15), dates)
print find_closest(dt(2014, 1, 25), dates)
```

EDIT in regards to Misha's comment:

To get the closest earlier date just modify the `find_closest` function:

```
def find_closest(mydate, dates):
   # see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5348215/1407427
   z = lambda seq,x: min([(x-i,i) for i in seq if x>=i] or [(0,None)])[1]
   return z(dates, mydate)
```

As you can see, this is a general function. You can feed it with dates, numbers or any other orderable data.

Comment: I think the use of `abs` isn't right here. He doesn't want the **closest** date, he wants the **closest date which is before the target date**.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a couple of lines of Python. Here's how I'd do it:

```
earlier_dates = [d for d in array_of_dates if d <= target_date]
if not earlier_dates:
    raise ValueError("no earlier dates to choose from")
return max(earlier_dates)
```