# Python - Get largest number in heap that is less than n

Tags: python, algorithm, heap, dynamic-programming

I'm having trouble finding the following functionality in Python:

> Given a set of numbers, return the largest number less than or equal to `n` or return `None` if no such number exists.

For example, given the list `[1, 3, 7, 10]` and `n = 9`, the function would return 7.

I'm looking for Python functionality similar to [Java's `TreeSet.lower`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#lower(E)).

I can use another data structure.  A heap seems appropriate.

The O(n) solution is too slow for the scale of the problem.  I'm looking for an O(log n) solution.

#### Background

I'm working on https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximise-sum.  The possible values range from 1 - 10^14, so using a sorted list with binary search is too slow.

My current thought is to iterate on [Python's heapq backing array](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/heapq.py) directly.  I was hoping there might be something more Pythonic.

Comment: Is the question asking for you to support repeated searching on the same data?  For a single search, converting an unordered list into another datastructure is almost certainly going to be O(n) already.

Comment: Yes, the problem a maximum subsequence problem with a twist.  So for `n` elements, I need to use the `lookup` described above.  So, I really need the `lookup` to take O(log n) time to support an overall complexity of O(n log n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use **bintrees** library for this : https://bitbucket.org/mozman/bintrees/src

Examples :

```
tree = bintrees.RBTree()
In [10]: tree.insert(5,1) 
In [11]: tree.insert(6,1) 
In [12]: tree.insert(10,1)
tree.ceiling_item(5)  -> (5,1)
```

The complexity of this operation is O(logN)

Comment: Yes, there's a couple good libraries for this I'd like to use.  Unfortunately, I can't use libraries on HackerRank.

Answer (score 2):

```
nextLowest  = lambda seq,x: min([(x-i,i) for i in seq if x>=i] or [(0,None)])
```

Usage:

```
t = [10, 20, 50, 200, 100, 300, 250, 150]
print nextLowest(t,55)
> 50
```

I take the above solution from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5348215/1604312).

Comment: I have done some timings. `t = xrange(1,10000000)
print nextLowest(t,10000000-1)` takes 3.6 seconds on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't make any assumptions about the ordering of the array, then I think the best you can do is O(n):

```
def largest_less_than(numlist, n):
    answer = min(numlist, key=lambda x: n-x if n>=x else float('inf'))
    if answer > n:
        answer = None
    return answer
```

If the question is about repeatedly getting the largest-less-than for different `n` values on the same dataset, then maybe one solution is using [bucket sort](http://www.geekviewpoint.com/python/sorting/bucketsort) to get your list sorted in O(n), and then use [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) repeatedly.

Comment: I have done some timings. `n = 10000000-1
num_list= xrange(1,10000000)` takes 2.1 seconds on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) for this. Below I have provided a simple algorithm for this:

```
numbers = [1, 3, 7, 10]
n = 9
largest_number = None
for number in numbers:    
    if number<=n:
        largest_number=number
    else:
        break

if largest_number:
    print 'value found ' + str(largest_number)
else:
    print 'value not found'
```

Comment: I have done some timings. `n = 10000000-1
numbers = xrange(1,10000000)` takes 2.3 seconds on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to support dynamic additions and removals from the list, then just sort it and use binary search to find the largest < n in O(log N) time.

Answer (score 0):

ig-melnyk's answer is probably the right way to complete this question.  But since HackerRank doesn't have a way to use libraries, here's an implementation of a [Left-Leaning Red Black Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-leaning_red%E2%80%93black_tree) that I used for the problem.

```
class LLRB(object):

    class Node(object):
        RED = True
        BLACK = False

        __slots__ = ['value', 'left', 'right', 'color']

        def __init__(self, value):
            self.value = value
            self.left = None
            self.right = None
            self.color = LLRB.Node.RED


        def flip_colors(self):
            self.color = not self.color
            self.left.color = not self.left.color
            self.right.color = not self.right.color


    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None


    def search_higher(self, value):
        """Return the smallest item greater than or equal to value.  If no such value
        can be found, return 0.

        """
        x = self.root
        best = None
        while x is not None:
            if x.value == value:
                return value
            elif x.value < value:
                x = x.left
            else:
                best = x.value if best is None else min(best, x.value)
                x = x.right

        return 0 if best is None else best

    @staticmethod
    def is_red(node):
        if node is None:
            return False
        else:
            return node.color == LLRB.Node.RED


    def insert(self, value):
        self.root = LLRB.insert_at(self.root, value)
        self.root.color = LLRB.Node.BLACK


    @staticmethod
    def insert_at(node, value):
        if node is None:
            return LLRB.Node(value)

        if LLRB.is_red(node.left) and LLRB.is_red(node.right):
            node.flip_colors()

        if node.value == value:
            node.value = value
        elif node.value < value:
            node.left = LLRB.insert_at(node.left, value)
        else:
            node.right = LLRB.insert_at(node.right, value)


        if LLRB.is_red(node.right) and not LLRB.is_red(node.left):
            node = LLRB.rotate_left(node)
        if LLRB.is_red(node.left) and LLRB.is_red(node.left.left):
            node = LLRB.rotate_right(node)

        return node
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease the number you're looking for until found.

This funtion will find the position of the largest number <= n in fs, a sorted list of integers.

If there are no numbers smaller or equal to n, it will return -1.

```
def findmaxpos(n):
  if n < fs[0]: return -1  
  while True:
    if n in fs: return fs.index(n)
    n-=1
```